# Obtener un elemento de hashtable

Tags: c#

Tengo un diccionario en el cual me piden que muestre definición a través de una palabra ingresada por el usuario. Por lo tanto la palabra ingresada la capturó en una variable llamada 'entrada' de tipo string.

```
Hashtable diccionario = New Hashtable();
Float valor;
String entrada;
Console.Write("ingrese la palabra");
entrada = Console.ReadLine();
valor = (float) diccionario.Item[entrada];
```

Bueno el problema es que yo espero que me devuelva en que posición se encuentra el key(entrada) y eh visto que en el visual studio 2010 estaría bien la sentencia. Pero en mi caso tengo visual studio 2012 y me muestra error en el:
Diccionario.Item
¿De que otra forma podría intentarlo?
Ya que necesito obtener la posición para mostrar el (key, value) del hashtable

Comment: Procura siempre incluir el error que te muestra. Ojalá como texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si analizamos la documentación

[Hashtable](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.5)

observaras que esa colección permite definir entradas del tipo `key-value`, no se necesita ninguna posición, ingresas el valor de la key y obtienes el valor.

Que tengas VS2010 o 2012 no es el problema, esta colección funciona igual porque c# por debajo es el mismo, no cambia.

Si estas usando

[Hashtable.Item[Object] Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.item?view=netframework-4.0#System_Collections_Hashtable_Item_System_Object_)

define el valor de la key y obtienes el valor asociado no su posición.

El código que estas escribiendo es correcto pero buscas un comportamiento que no es el que se espera.